# scrollable div overflows its parent instead of scrolling

Tags: css

I have some cards with fixed width and which are growable up to a maximum height. Each card contains a list of items which should be scrollable if the card has reached its maximum height:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h3>
      Header
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5>Title</h5>
    <div class="scroll-view">
      <ul>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <h5>Footer</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

.

```
.card {
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 12em;
  max-height: 24rem;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid aliceblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-header {
  background-color: gray;
}

.card-body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.scroll-view {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Unfortunately, what ends up happening is that once there are enough items to exceed the maximum height, they just overflow past the end of the card instead of scrolling: https://jsfiddle.net/wg4160fh/21/

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really need the `.scroll-view` div inside of the `.card-body`. But if you want to keep the footer intact, you'd need to define a height on the `.scroll-view` in order to hide anything.

You could also use `overflow-y: scroll` or just `overflow: scroll` on the `card-body` to remove the `.scroll-view`

### Example using defined height on `.scroll-view`

```css
.card {
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 12em;
  max-height: 24rem;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid aliceblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.card-header {
  background-color: gray;
}

.card-body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
      overflow: scroll;
}

.scroll-view {
  background: Teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h3>
      Header
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5>Title</h5>
    <div class="scroll-view">
      <ul>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
        <li>An item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <h5>Footer</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Edit

I clearly missed the card height (sorry). But you'll just add the `overflow:scroll` property to the `.card` element instead. I've updated the example.

### Edit 2

I've updated the snippet to place the overflow on the `.card-body` and moving the footer area to a separate div.

Comment: I don't want the scroll view to have a definite height though. I would like it to grow up to a maximum size

Comment: @Katie If you want the div to be scrollable, something has to be hidden. You said in your question, you want it to "be scrollable when it reaches max height". If you don't set a height somewhere, the div will grow and not be scrollable within that specific area. You could use `vh` to define the vertical height, based on the screen size instead of a more absolute value.

Comment: The .card element has a max-height of `24rem`. Once the list grows large enough to cause the card to reach this max-height, it should stop growing and start scrolling.

Comment: The purpose of the `scroll-view` inside of the `card-body` is to ensure the title and footer always appear above and below the list (outside of the `scroll-view`).
If I try adding `overflow-y: auto` to the `card-body` or `card`, all it does is make the entire card-body or card scrollable (as your code snippet is doing), which is not what I would like. I'd like for *only* the `scroll-view` contents to be scrollable.

Comment: Updated the answer, moved a few things around and I think it's doing what you're asking for now.

Comment: This still isn't really what I'm looking for. The card itself should not be scrollable and shouldn't have a scrollbar. Also, I don't want the whole card-body to be scrollable, just the scroll-view inside of it. The title and footer should still be visible above and below the scroll-view, and be inside of the card-body div.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help @Katie . Hopefully you figure it out.

Comment: This has been stumping me for a couple of weeks now, unfortunately. I really appreciate your attempts to help though, thank you :)

Comment: @katie -- In your comment (3/19 @ 20:23) you mentioned adding the overflow to the card-body hides the footer. But that's only because of how the HTML is structured. If you pull the footer out to a new div, that should fix that particular issue. The inter scroll-view div has to have a height (or max-height) to successfully scroll inside of card (from my tests). This codepen might display the rendered code better than SO does for the idea. https://codepen.io/mcmullengreg/pen/LdOPyg?editors=1100#0

Comment: The card body has padding, and the title and footer are meant to be inside of this padded area (the title refers to the list of items, and the footer is in reality a button that adds a new item. Both should be inside of the body but outside of the scrollable list). Taking them outside of it and making them direct children of the card doesn't really make a lot of sense to me. It would make things more brittle, less DRY (and less maintainable) since I would need to repeat css properties (like padding and background-color) across multiple classes that could have just been on .card-body

Comment: Got it, just another wrench. I think I'm officially at a loss, wish you the best of luck.